# New folder not captured by source control in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control

I am new to this... When I make changes in files or add a new file in Visual Studio Code, it will be captured by the source control panel with a blue icon, but when I add a new folder, this will not be given the blue icon or show up in source control panel... why? And how to make it there? Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0vDX.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the new directory is empty, `git` won't track it. You'll need to add a `.gitkeep` file or some other "dummy" file.

See [How can I add a blank directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-a-blank-directory-to-a-git-repository)